# Pressing enter on the search bar does not reload page react

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Within a react SPA if I change the URL and press enter it does not refresh the page. If I F5 it refreshes the page or if I press end and hit enter.

I want it to update the state with the change on the URL

Is there a reason why this would happen?